# Are Chinese companies hiring "developer cheerleaders"?

Tags: china, programming-productivity

I think the source for this is [this Trending In China Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/trendinginchina/photos/pcb.603461796423974/603459879757499/?type=1&theater):

> Internet companies across China are embracing programming
>   cheerleaders, pretty, talented girls that help create a fun work
>   environment. Their job includes buying programmers breakfast,
>   chitchatting and playing ping-pong with them. According to the HR
>   manager of an Internet company that hired three such cheerleaders, its
>   programmers are mostly male and terrible at socializing, and the
>   presence of these girls have greatly improved their job efficiency and
>   motivation.

But this claim has been reprinted by more mainstream media including. [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-3208366/Programming-cheerleaders-hired-motivate-Chinese-employees.html), seems to only have a Facebook post as a source.

Are there any better sources to this claim?

Comment: -1 because my company doesn't hire cheerleaders and I'm jealous :(

Comment: If the Daily Mail printed it then it's probably untrue, or at best a massive exaggeration and highly misleading.

Comment: @dont_shog_me_bro which means that it’s a good thing he asked about it here.

Comment: As a developer, I'm hoping for developer-groupies..... and my standards for "acceptable" are pretty low, so someone get on that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably as true as "American companies hire massagers for developers". As in very few do it (Google). As for your question on better sources, I found https://gizmodo.com/startups-in-china-are-hiring-women-as-programmer-motiv-1825529335

> It remains to be seen how widespread programmer motivators are in China, but the Times noted that a job search site run by Chinese tech company Baidu showed seven companies with job ads for such a position.

Comment: The Google one comes with much better PR (of course): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZASRmfUMOk

Comment: Someone that gives a massage is a masseuse or masseur, not massager.  A massager is an object.